# Find a solution $x\in\mathbb{Z_{\mathrm{784}}}$ for $x\cdot\overline{602}=\overline{308}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I know that I have to find a positive integer $x$ that I can multiply with $602$ and then divide the result by $784$ so that the remainder of that
integer division is $308$. I am sure that this is quite a trivial
question, but I simply don't get it. How do I efficiently calculate $x$ in its residue class? Obviously trial and error is not an option here. Can someone please enlighten me on this topic?

Comment: Note that $602x \equiv 308 \pmod{784} \iff 602x = 308 + 784t$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hint:  your life gets easier if you notice that $14$ divides each of $602,308,684$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\gcd(784,602)=14$$

So using the extended euclidean algorithm we can find integers $s$ and $t$ such that:

$$784s+602t=14\implies602t \equiv 14 \pmod{784}$$

You can check that $s=10,t=-13$ satisfies the above. Then

$$308=14\cdot22\equiv602\cdot(-13)\cdot22\pmod{784}$$

And hence $$x\equiv-13\cdot22\equiv498\pmod{784}$$

is a solution.

Comment: @AndreasSchliebitz I've added another solution to my answer.

Comment: The answer is $x \equiv 50 \pmod{56}$.  You found one particular solution.  However, there are others.

Comment: I asked for one solution. That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

$784=2^4\cdot 7^2$ is the unique prime factorization, so

$$602x\equiv 308\pmod{784}\iff \begin{cases}602x\equiv 308\pmod{2^4}\\602x\equiv 308\pmod{7^2}\end{cases}$$

$$602x\equiv 308\pmod{2^4}\stackrel{:2}\iff 301x\equiv 154\pmod{2^3}$$

$$\iff 5x\equiv 2\equiv 10\pmod{8}\stackrel{:5}\iff x\equiv 2\pmod{8}$$

$$602x\equiv 308\pmod{7^2}\iff 14x\equiv 14\pmod{7^2}$$

$$\stackrel{:14}\iff x\equiv 1\pmod{7}$$

By [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), the solution is $x\equiv 50\pmod{56}$.

---

Different solution:

$$602x\equiv 308\pmod{784}\stackrel{:14}\iff 43x\equiv 22\pmod{56}$$

Then notice that $\gcd(43,56)=1$, so you can use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find $43^{-1}\bmod 56$.

Subtract consecutive equations:

$$56=(1)(56)+(0)(43)\\ 43=(0)(56)+(1)(43)\\13=(1)(56)+(-1)(43)\\4=(-3)(56)+(4)(43)\\1=(10)(56)+(-13)(43)$$

Therefore $(-13)(43)\equiv 1\pmod{56}$, so $43^{-1}\equiv -13\pmod{56}$.

Therefore $x\equiv 43^{-1}\cdot 22\equiv -13\cdot 22\equiv -6\equiv 50\pmod{56}$.

Comment: So if I get this right, this calculates the smallest x in the residue class which satisfies the equation, right? Pretty neat. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreasSchliebitz You can say that $$x\equiv \{50,106,162,218,274,330,386,442,498,554,610,666,722,778\}\pmod{784}$$  
are all the solutions, if you insist on showing your solutions using mod $784$.